# Asterisk: AGI-Script after Caller is engaged with Callee

Tags: asterisk, phone-call, agi

Is it possible to execute an AGI-Script after caller is engaged with Callee?
Probably it's tricky: Callees are in a queue.
If yes, I have no clue where to find the lines.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the option G in your Dial() and call your AGI application there.

> G - If the call is answered, transfer the calling party to the specified priority and the called party to the specified priority plus one.

```
exten => s,1,Dial(SIP/user,,G(test,ext,1))

[test]
exten => ext, 1, AGI()
```

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_Dial

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean.

You can run dialplan commands using macro on answer in command dial(M param).

You can run agi before calling.